# google assistant command to open an android app's feature without its app name

Tags: android, google-assistant

im doing an SOS App for android.
I want to trigger the SOS with google assistant.
Can i use a phrase ( like "Save me" or "help" ) as google assistant command to open my app?
Is it possible to open an app without its name with google assistant ?